# Inserting String as datetime2(0) into SQL Server 2012 using JDBC causes error

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I gather data from an external source and wish to insert it into my SQL Server 2012 database. When I attempt to insert a String, formatted as follows: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss", which complies with [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)., it doesn't go quite as I want to.

For clarification, the first column of my table is of type datetime2(0).

Upon executing the following code

```
insertData() {
...

insert.execute("INSERT INTO [LindTrading].[dbo].[Bloomberg]" +
                " VALUES" +
                "(" +
                trade.getTimestamp() + " ," +
                trade.getAmount() + "," +
                trade.getPrice() + "," +
                trade.getTicker() +
                ")");

...
}
```

An example of a timestamp is "2014-07-22 00:04:08".

I get the following error:
(...).SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '00'.

Also, getTicker() returns a string such as "CF US EQUITY", and the spaces surrounding US seem to cause similar problems, when I attempt to insert into a varchar(25) column.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does trade.getTimestamp() return EXACTLY?

Comment: getTimestape() returns a String formatted as explained above, that is: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss". An example is shown below the code box above.

Comment: Are you not missing single quotation marks around the timestamp?

Comment: That was indeed the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string containing the datetime should be within apostrophes, like

'2014-07-23 12:00:00'

And not only

2014-07-23 12:00:00

Is this the case?

Comment: Thanks a lot - this solved the issue! I assumed that JDBC took care of that since it was a String, but I guess not.